# why is statement after async is executed before statement with async function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

```
function renderLoader() {
    console.log("Loading");
}

function getResults() {
    setTimeout(myTimeout, 3000)
}  

function myTimeout() {
    console.log("The Results");
}

function clearLoader() {
   console.log("Loading over");
}

const controlSearch = async () => {
    renderLoader();
    await getResults();
    clearLoader();
}

controlSearch();
```

I'm new to async/await. I expected the result of above code to be

```
Loading  //then wait for 3 seconds
Results
Loading over
```

But instead it produced this,

```
Loading
Loading over //then wait for 3 secs
Results
```

I don't understand what I m doing wrong?

Comment: `getResults` does not return `Promise`

Answer (score 0):

`await`/`async` play with promises. As is, `getResults` synchronously returns `undefined`, while it should return a `Promise` that `await` will, well, await:

```js
function getResults() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      myTimeout();
      resolve();
    }, 3000)
  });
}
```

Or:

```js
function getResults() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000)
  }).then(myTimeout);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await.

Comment: I had read the documentation. What I understood was that even If I don't explicitly mention return, a promise is returned. Now, I know that it is 'undefined'.